# How do I get 5 values from 3 different tables? [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

**MYSQL**

I am trying to get 5 values from 3 separate tables where each value is in it's own column.

The values I am trying to get are: **SC_Name, SC_Description, AR_Name, AR_Description, AR_id**

I have 3 tables where I am pulling the data from:

```
Service_Category
Area_Responsibility
Key_Scar
```

Service_Category contains the following columns:

```
id
SC_Name
SC_Description
```

Area_Responsibility contains the following columns:

```
id
AR_Name
AR_Description
```

Key_SCAR contains the following columns:

```
id
KS_id
SC_id
AR_id
```

The intention of having 3 separate tables is so that I can separate the data better in the first two tables and then in the third table link them together on the basis of KS_id and the id from Service_Category and the id from Area_Responsibility.

At the moment I have the following individual queries (KS_id is always 1):

```
SELECT a.SC_Name, a.SC_Description 
FROM Service_Category AS a 
where a.id IN (SELECT SC_id 
FROM Key_SCAR 
WHERE KS_id = 1);
    
SELECT a.AR_Name, a.AR_Description 
FROM Area_Responsibility AS a 
where a.id IN (SELECT AR_id 
FROM Key_SCAR 
WHERE KS_id = 1);
```

I would like to join these into one query that outputs: SC_Name, SC_Description, AR_Name, AR_Description and AR_id.

I have tried to union these two queries as follows:

```
SELECT a.SC_Name, a.SC_Description 
FROM Service_Category AS a 
where a.id IN (SELECT SC_id 
FROM Key_SCAR 
WHERE KS_id = 1) 
UNION 
SELECT b.AR_Name, b.AR_Description 
FROM Area_Responsibility AS b 
where a.id IN (SELECT AR_id 
FROM Key_SCAR 
WHERE KS_id = 1);
```

This however does not work for my output as the interpreter I'm using places AR_Name & AR_Description under the column headings SC_Name and SC_Description. I need each of the outputted values to be in their own columns.

I hope this explains it well enough, and thank you in advance for the assistance!

Comment: please provide few sample data and expected output if possible.

Comment: The Manual and look up JOIN, its really one of the basic building blocks of SQL

Comment: Hi: It's all good, the answer provided by Groovy guy below has allowed me to get the solution. I'm still learning so having people help is amazing. Thank you for the feedback all.

Comment: That answer _might_ work - but only if you have same ID's in both tables.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you can try to achieve your required results by using the join method,

```
SELECT SC.SC_Name, SC.SC_Description, AR.AR_Name, AR.AR_Description, KS.AR_id
FROM Key_SCAR KS 
INNER JOIN Service_Category SC ON SC.id = KS.SC_id
INNER JOIN Area_Responsibility AR ON AR.id = KS.AR_id
WHERE KS.KS_id = 1;
```

Comment: Try using `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` instead and that'll work as well